# How to integrate VSTS to angular 4

Tags: asp.net, angular, tfs, asp.net-web-api2, azure-devops

We are currently migrating an app that 
is written in WPF to web(Angular 4 + Web API 2).
This app is for Agile similar to JIRA.

We would like to integrate VSTS in that we would like users to get/create workitem.
This feature is currently working in our WPF, it uses DLL's from microsoft(Mirosoft.TeamFoundationServer, etc).
When users get/create workitem the first time, WPF prompts a 
Log in dialog which only happens once per user as after logging in it store a token/key on users PC.

Now, in web, we would like to achieve the same in that the user will only have to sign in once.
Using PATs or access token is not an option for us as it has an expiration.
Using users credential or basic authentication is not also an option for us as users credential 
to vsts is not stored in our DB.

I have tried adding the DLL that wpf uses to our API but it doesn't work as it is 
returning Unauthorize access error(Geting users credential is not an option).
I have search for angular library for VSTS and I did not found one.

Comment: TFS has a REST API. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

Comment: Thx for answering. We can't use the rest API as it requires access token  which is not an  option for us as it has expiration and also it is only available for tfs 2017 - we are using tfs 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [ASP.NET Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). When using impersonation, ASP.NET applications can execute with the Windows identity (user account) of the user making the request.

Here is a blog you could refer to: [Setting up impersonation for ASP.NET TFS API apps](http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/rorystreet/2015/06/24/SettingUpImpersonationForASPNETTFSAPIApps.aspx).

Comment: Thx for answering. Unfortunately this is not an option for us cause we could not change our authentication to windows authentication. Is there a way to use impersonation without using windows authentication?

Comment: I didn't see such a way for now. You could consider upgrading to TFS 2017 and use the PAT authentication. Although it has expiration, you can set one year expiration.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading and using PAT is not an option for us. Seems like we hit the wall now. Well, anyway, thank you for taking time to answer my question ^^.